# Is there a way to stop generating rep and still participate?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined, reputation

I would like to not earn reputation, but still participate in this site. Is that possible? Why or why not?

Comment: Give away bounties to good answers with any reputation that you've earned.

Comment: What do you classify as "participate in this site"? There are questions here. If you have an answer for them (that hasn't already been put forth), there's nothing preventing you from adding it to the question.

Comment: @Coronus That would change his reputation, which he appears to want to avoid.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Hmm I read it as "I don't care about rep"

Comment: @Coronus - my problem is that I see no reason to devote my time to answering others questions on the main site if the current system is not up to my standards. That's why I'm posting in meta. If the time comes when the system is up to my standards then I will contribute to the actual site. But until then, I will only contribute in full effect to the meta site.

Comment: You're not contributing here. You're asking pointless questions that display a stunning lack of understanding about the entire point of this site/network. You have been alternating between requesting fundamental changes to the way the site works and asking unnecessary, passive-agressive questions to make a point. Come back when you understand how the site works and why we do what we do.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I don't know. My work week has been a lot less boring now that I've had all of these brilliant, in-depth analyses of the SE network to read on meta.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you could participate in the site without changing your reputation would be making useful comments on other people's posts. Theoretically, you could achieve this by making every post you make community wiki, but that would be abusive behavior and would probably get you suspended.

Reputation is a measurement of how much the community as a whole trusts you. We cannot simply allow an individual to prevent the community from making that measurement.

Comment: it is unless we abolish the reputation system

Comment: @kraftydevil So basically you want to ignore the whole way the network works.....

Comment: Abolishing the rep system would cause more problems than it would solve.  How would you determine who can do what?  Who has the ability to keep the site clean and moderated?  Not to mention, without rep, we'll never get new users.  Everyone wants their imaginary internet points.

Comment: @fbueckert- I love those questions and wish you'd really ask them sometime.

Comment: @kraftydevil No.  You need a better grasp of the function of the SE network.  I, for one, think the system works well.  There isn't a problem to be solved here, other than you learning more about StackExchange.

Comment: I've been observing for years and I'm still not impressed.

Comment: @kraftydevil Stack Exchange might not be for you, then :)